# rotate a Vector to reach orthogonality with another vector

Tags: c++, geometry

I have 2 vectors `(V1{x1, y1, z1}, V2{x2, y2, z2})` , and I want rotate `V1` around *X-Axis*, *Y-Axis* and *Z-Axis* to be parallel to `V2`. I want to find 3 rotation angles.
Is there any general formula I can use to find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do that in this way:

```
    A = V1xV2; //Cross product, this gives the axis of rotation
    sin_angle =  length(A)/( |V1| |V2|); //sine of the angle between vectors

    angle = asin(sin_angle);
    A_n = normalize(A);
```

Now you can build a quaternion with angle and A_n.

```
    q = (A_n.x i + A_n.y j + A_n.z k)*sin(angle/2) + cos(angle/2);
```

And use [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles#Conversion) formulas to get your euler angles.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need the rotation angles, or is it a rotation matrix you're looking for. If the latter, you can do it the way it's done in OpenFOAM: http://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.1.x/blob/master/src/OpenFOAM/primitives/transform/transform.H#L45

Note that in OpenFOAM for `vector` the `&` operator denotes the inner product, the `^` operator the cross product and `*` is the outer product. The `sqr` function computes the element-wise squares, `magSqr` the square of the magnitude of a `vector` (i.e. `v&v`).

Comment: A very small number, if compiled for double precision it is `1.0e-300`, for float it is `1.0e-150`.